# CountVectorizer on list of integers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization, text-processing

I have list of integers as below:

`mylist = [111,113,114,115,112,115,234,643,565,.....]`

I have many lists like this with more than 500 integers on which I wanted to run CountVectorizer. As far as I know, CountVectorizer only tokenize list of string than integers.

I have tried to first convert each element of these lists into str via

`mylist_string = list(map(lambda x: str(x), mylist))`

but since the list is too long, it is taking very large time.

Is there any way to tokenize the integer lists or is there any efficient way to convert the list of numbers to list of strings.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "tokenize the integers"?  A CountVectorizer expects a sequence of *text documents* that it turns into a document-term matrix. What exactly do you expect CountVectorizer to do with a list of integer? Also, how slow is "too slow", what you show here should be very fast.

Comment: The default regexp in CountVectorizer selects tokens of 2 or more "alphanumeric" characters. So if you supply it a string representation of your list, it should work as expected. But you need to first explain more about the problem. "`tokenize the integer lists`" and  "`convert the list of numbers to list of strings`" are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, its redundant to use map with lambda, that might be the reason for the slow down,
you could just use `map` without lambda like below

```
mylist = [111,113,114,115,112,115,234,643,565]
mylist_string = map(str, mylist) # use list(map(str, mylist)) for python 3
# ['111', '113', '114', '115', '112', '115', '234', '643', '565']
```

alternatively, you could try `list comprehension`

```
mylist = [111,113,114,115,112,115,234,643,565]
mylist_string = [str(x) for x in mylist]
# ['111', '113', '114', '115', '112', '115', '234', '643', '565']
```

Comment: Thanks BUT In your first option, mylist_string would not give you the list as map function is lazy loading. I have tried the second option but as I said in the question it is not efficient at all since my list is in thousands.

Comment: @Maharshi list in thousands is tiny. `list(map(str, data))` should be very fast

Comment: @Maharshi, yes, you would need `list(map(str, data))` if you are using python 3, for python 2, the list can be omitted